# SQL request, Sum of a subselect to group by month

Tags: sql

I've got 3 tables. To make it more understandable I transposed it to something easy like a schedule for different sport activity.

1.
The first table "sports" is the different sports.
It contains the id and the name of this sport.

```
Table "sports"
+----+-------+
| id | Sport |
+----+-------+
| 1  | Judo  |
+----+-------+
| 2  | Boxe  |
+----+-------+
```

2.
The second table "classes" are the different classes that actually happened. Each class is related to a sport and a date.
It contains the id, the date of the class, the id of the sport it's related too, and a unique id to make it unique, combining the date and the sport id.

```
table "classes"
+----+----------+------------+--------------+
| id | id_sport | dates      | unique_key   |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+
| 1  | 1        | 2017-03-10 | 1_2017-03-10 |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+
| 2  | 2        | 2017-03-10 | 2_2017-03-10 |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+
| 3  | 2        | 2017-03-17 | 2_2017-03-17 |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+
```

3.
The third table "appointment" collects every presence.
It contains the name of the person who came, the id of the sport, and the unique key of the class. I know, in this table the column id_sport was not necessary because we can find it in the table classes.

```
Table "appointments"
+----+---------+----------+--------------+
| id | student | id_sport | id_class     |
+----+---------+----------+--------------+
| 1  | Tom     | 1        | 1_2017-03-10 |
+----+---------+----------+--------------+
| 2  | Sam     | 1        | 1_2017-03-10 |
+----+---------+----------+--------------+
| 3  | Mat     | 2        | 2_2017-03-10 |
+----+---------+----------+--------------+
| 4  | Mat     | 2        | 2_2017-03-17 |
+----+---------+----------+--------------+
| 5  | Tom     | 2        | 2_2017-03-10 |
+----+---------+----------+--------------+
```

I'm trying to sort some stats. I try to find the number of persons who were present for a specific sport, every month.

With this request, I try to find the number of persons present at the boxe class :

```
SELECT
MONTH(classes.dates) AS Month,
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM appointments
   WHERE appointments.id_sport = sports.id AND appointments.id_class = 
classes.unique_key AND sports.id = 2 LIMIT 1) AS nb_appointment   
FROM sports
INNER JOIN classes ON classes.id_sport = sports.id
WHERE sports.id = 2
ORDER BY Month
```

The result of this is

```
+-------+---------------+
| Month | nb_appointment|
+-------+---------------+
| 3     | 2             |
+-------+---------------+
| 3     | 1             |
+-------+---------------+
```

What i want is THE SUM for the : Month 3 => nb_appointment 3

If i had also some month 4, 5 etc, it would display also the sum of appointment for these month.

I tryed with Group by Month, but it does not ad the number of appointment, just shows the last ...

Any ideas ?

Here is the sql fiddle of what i tried
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/733782/1

Also I tried wrapping the select in a SUM, but still doesn't seems to work : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ae510/1

I'm starting in php/sql, sorry if this question seems dumb.

Comment: I think since you selected sport_id =2 you have to get nb_appointment 3 and not 5 right?

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(distinct student) , Month(c.dates)
   from appointment a 
   inner join classes c
   on a.id_class = c.unique_key
   where c.id_sports = 2
group by Month(c.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually wrap a "SUM" around your sub-query:

```
SELECT
MONTH(classes.dates) AS Month,  
SUM(
(SELECT count(*)
   FROM appointment
   WHERE appointment.id_sport = sports.id 
   AND appointment.id_classes = classes.unique_key 
   AND sports.id = 2 LIMIT 1) 
) AS nb_appointment   
FROM sports
INNER JOIN classes ON classes.id_sport = sports.id
WHERE sports.id = 2
ORDER BY Month
```

This gives the answer 3 (your post said you expected nb_appointments to be 5, but I think it is 3??)

Comment: Thank you, I already tried this... It looks like it works, but if I have several months, it doesnt. If I have month 3, 4, 5 It returns the first month (3) and the sum of everymonth : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ae510/1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally it works by wrapping in a sum() AND adding a group by, like this :

```
SELECT
MONTH(classes.dates) AS Month,
SUM(
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM appointment
   WHERE appointment.id_sport = sports.id AND appointment.id_classes = 
classes.unique_key AND sports.id = 2 LIMIT 1)
  )AS nb_appointment   
FROM sports
INNER JOIN classes ON classes.id_sport = sports.id
WHERE sports.id = 2
GROUP BY Month
ORDER BY Month
```

Thanks !